# How to avoid XAML namespace import in every Window

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it somehow possible to avoid `xmlns:Engine="clr-namespace..."` if i need the same namespace in each of my application windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm agree with HCL, I think it can't be done and adding the namespace will not consume more resources.

I will give you an alternative. You can change the the window template (or create one of your own) to make it include the namespace for you.

In my computer, for VS2010, the path of the template is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\WPF\3082

Note that one is for vb.Net, there is a CSHARP directory as well.

**Edit**:

As far as I Know, the templates are for each computer, not for each project, but when you edit the template you can use conditionals, for example:

```
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
```

You can use the $rootnamespace$ constant to check for a specific project and then add the namespace or not. Maybe a constant with the current project name exists, i don't know, but $rootnamespace$ should be enought for this pourpose.

Comment: +1 Cool idea, if possible for specific projects or solutions, it would be even better

Answer (score 3):

If it's your own the sourcecode to the assembly you using in the Engine namespace you can accually totaly remove the prefix requerment and the demand of adding something. With this little trick you just append your own namespaces to the xaml namespace (that allready is included).

In your "Engine" project (not the project where you have the xmlns:Engine line, **can't** be the same project where you use it, it will not work then) make sure you have the WindowsBase reference added and then add the following in the the AssemblyInfo.cs/AssemblyInfo.vb file (c#: found in the Properties folder) (vb: you need to use the "Show all Files" button and then you will find it in the My Project folder):

c#:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "The.Class.Namespace")]
```

vb:

```
<Assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "The.Class.Namespace")>
```

You can do this several times if you project have classes in more then one namespace you wanna use in the other projects xaml.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to avoid this. However declaring a namespace does not mean that it consumes resources (at runtime).